# Facebook fan page using webview

Tags: android

In my app, i am using webview. It is basically intended for my fan page. But as it is a webview, users can navigate at other places too. 
Is it illegal to do so? I mean making a facebook page in a webview? Will it create any copyright issues?

```
tC = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tcWV);
    tC.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    tC.loadUrl("https://touch.facebook.com/hahacricket");
    tC.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
    tC.setWebViewClient(new tCWVClient());
    tC.canGoBack();
    tC.canGoForward();
```

The other question I want to ask is how can I prevent users to go to the links other than my page.

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        Log.d("URL", url);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent user got to another website you have to check for the url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("https://touch.facebook.com/hahacricket")){
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: url.startsWith(). never knew this existed. thank you very much.